# Windows Server 2012 Standard/Datacenter Additional License Install (4 cpu) Activate

Tags: windows-server-2012, datacenter, licensing

I have a 4 x 10 core (80 threads) machine. I've installed `Windows Server Datacenter 2012` and now I'm only able to use 2 CPUs. Windows Server Datacenter 2012 only allows 2 CPUs per license key. I do have 2 license keys but I have no idea where to input the 2nd key. I'm only using 1 license right now. When I use cinebench, the cpu usage stays at 50% in the task manager.

How do I install my 2nd license key?

Answer (score 0):

The license keys in Windows don't actually enforce processor limits, but the editions do. So make sure that your system properties says your installation is Datacenter. If not, then you need to change the key to one of your Datacenter keys.

Comment: It is datacenter 2012.

Comment: Yes!

i'm using hyper-v and i'm able to get 64 threads out of 80. Without hyper-v server 2012 i can't use 100% cpu usage for some reason.. but it is using all the processors, just not the full power. something to do with cpu scheduling??

Comment: If you have 40 cores but 80 threads, that means you have hyper-threading enabled. It's almost impossible to reach 100% utilization on all cores with hyper-threading enabled. You can get close, but 70% would be good.